# Solaris kstat sdX disk nread counter value decreasing

Tags: solaris, hard-drive

I get strange disk io nread (bytes read) counter values (from kstat) on Solaris. Example of collected nread value for sd6 disk collected in 30s interval (command `kstat -n sd6`):

```
768579416
768579416
768579416
768579416
768579416
768579416
768579416
768496080
768496080
768496080
768496080
768496080
768496080
768496080
768496080
768530896
768530896
768447560
768447560
768447560
```

One would suppose that the relative read bytes count can't be negative..
I wonder what can couse  this situation and whether there is more reliable disk io data available.

Some info about the system:

```
machine:~ # uname -a
SunOS machine 5.10 Generic_127112-11 i86pc i386 i86pc
machine:~ # cat /etc/release 
                        Solaris 10 11/06 s10x_u3wos_10 X86
           Copyright 2006 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
                        Use is subject to license terms.
                           Assembled 14 November 2006
```

Comment: it happens on almost every machine, on each for several disks

Answer (score 0):

Nreads should indeed grow, not decrease. What about the other statistics (reads, writes) and does the same behavior happen with other devices ?
What Solaris release / kernel patch level are you using ? It might just be a bug.

Comment: I have added the machine info to the question

Comment: What about the other statistics (reads, writes) ?

Comment: other statistics are OK, not decreasing